# php ajax multiple dropdown pagination

Tags: php, ajax, pagination

I am trying to build a multiple dropdown search based on php  and ajax. When the page is loaded or refreshed it should display full data list with pagination and once any dropdown item is changed it should then show only matching records with pagination. So far I have managed to do the full list loading part with pagination. For the dropdown change part- I have managed to get the loading of matching data with pagination. Here is the problem. For example, if I select BMW as car 'Make' pagination shows 2 page numbers (3 in the database, 2 per page). But when I click either of the page numbers- it goes back to the full car listing with pagination. here is my code(please ask if More details required)-

**script**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#model').prop("disabled", true);
               
                function load_data(page){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'carlist_load.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {page_no:page},
                        success:function(data){
                            $("#carlist").html(data);
                        }
                    })
                }
                load_data();
                $(document).on("click","#pagination a", function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var page_id = $(this).attr("id");
                    load_data(page_id);
                }) 
               
               
               function load_datab(page){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'carlist_search.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {page_no:page},
                        success:function(data){
                            $("#carlist").html(data);
                        }
                    })
                }
                //load_datab();
                $(document).on("click","#pagination a", function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var page_id = $(this).attr("id");
                    load_datab(page_id);
                }) 

 $("#make").change(function() {
                     $('#model').prop("disabled", false);
                var selectedmake = $("#make").val();
                var selectedgearbox = $("#gearbox").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'carlist_search.php',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {selected_make:selectedmake,selected_gearbox:selectedgearbox},
                    success:function(data){
                        $("#carlist").html(data);
                    }
                })
                });

**carlist_load.php**

    //load data
    $page_per_limit=2;
        $page='';
        if(isset($_POST['page_no'])){
            $page=$_POST['page_no'];
        }else{
            $page=1;
        }
        $offset = ($page-1)*$page_per_limit;
        $args=array(
                ':type'     =>  'general',  
            );
        $query="SELECT * FROM cars WHERE cartype=:type LIMIT {$offset},{$page_per_limit}";
     

          ............
    .............
    ...........
    $total_row=$stmt->rowCount();
        if($total_row>0)
        {

        foreach($result as $row){
                  $output  .= "<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-pad">
    .........

    //pagination

    $args=array(
                ':type'     =>  'general',  
            );
        $query="SELECT * FROM cars WHERE cartype=:type ";
    ......
    ......
    $total_row=$stmt->rowCount();
        $total_page = ceil($total_row/$page_per_limit);
        $prev_page=$page-1;
        $next_page=$page+1;
        
        $output .="<div class='pagination-box text-center ml-3' id='pagination'>
    ...........

**carlist_search.php**

    //load data
        $page_per_limit=2;
            $page='';
            if(isset($_POST['page_no'])){
                $page=$_POST['page_no'];
            }else{
                $page=1;
            }
            $offset = ($page-1)*$page_per_limit;
    
        $make   =  $_POST['selected_make'];
                    $model     =  $_POST['selected_model'];
                    $gearbox     =  $_POST['selected_gearbox'];
            $args=array(
                    ':type'     =>  'general',  
                );
            $query="SELECT * FROM cars WHERE cartype=:type
                    AND make like '%".$make."%'
                    AND model like '%".$model."%' 
                    AND gearbox like '%".$gearbox."%'
                    LIMIT {$offset},{$page_per_limit}";
         
    
              ............
        .............
        ...........
        $total_row=$stmt->rowCount();
            if($total_row>0)
            {
    
            foreach($result as $row){
                      $output  .= "<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-pad">
        .........
    
        //pagination
     
    
        $make   =  $_POST['selected_make'];
                    $model     =  $_POST['selected_model'];
                    $gearbox     =  $_POST['selected_gearbox'];
        $args=array(
                    ':type'     =>  'general',  
                );
            $query="SELECT * FROM cars WHERE cartype=:type 
    AND make like '%".$make."%'
                AND model like '%".$model."%' 
                AND gearbox like '%".$gearbox."%'
    ";
        ......
        ......
        $total_row=$stmt->rowCount();
            $total_page = ceil($total_row/$page_per_limit);
            $prev_page=$page-1;
            $next_page=$page+1;
            
            $output .="<div class='pagination-box text-center ml-3' id='pagination'>
        ...........
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? I would assume that switching the pagination to load data through AJAX could resolve the problem

Comment: @NicoHaase, thank you for your response. It is actually loading data and pagination through ajax. My guess is, something wrong with my pagination page numbers, I tried to give the pagination div two different ids in two different pages (carlist_load and carlist_search), but that did not work either.

Comment: What **exactly** does not work? What have you tried to debug the problem? Please add all clarification to your quesiton by editing it, not to the comment section

Comment: @NicoHaase thanks again. I understand you are trying to help. I have mentioned in my question what is not working and also in my comment what I have tried to solve it. if you have time please read it through. In terms of debugging I am not getting any errors, just the wrong set of page numbers.

Comment: Please share more details - what have you tried to debug the problem? Like: are the event handlers registered properly? The given code doesn't even compile, so it's pretty difficult for others to provide help

Comment: Additionally, is this a PHP or a JS problem? If any click causes a redirect, please share the code triggering the problem

Comment: right off I noticed duplicate code: `$(document).on("click","#pagination a", function(e) {`

Comment: @TimMorton. thanks for your advice. did you mean same duplicate id? I have tried with two different ids now #pagination and #test. but still getting the same result.